# AVPlayer audio volume too slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avplayer, volume

I am using `AVPlayer` to play a `m3u8` streaming. This is what I have done.

```
self.audioUrl=[[array objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:1];
self.avPlayer=[[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:self.audioUrl]];
[self.avPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
```

But my problem is the volume is too slow. I want to play audio only. But why it's volume is too slow?
 I did something like this too after these lines.

```
@try {
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&error];
} @catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"-----EXCEPTION-----%@",exception);
```

But still same. Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: I added it to appdelegate then problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the volume then play:

```
[_avPlayer setVolume:1.0];
[_avPlayer play];
```